# Is it possible to hide all shares of posts that aren't from a person?

Tags: facebook

So my Facebook newsfeed seems to be littered with a lot of junk lately, and the majority of that seems to be this epidemic of people sharing posts and pictures from entities that as far as I can tell are not actual people.  The closest thing I can describe these entities as are "comedy" pages or some sort of FB page that just posts random crap, and people reshare the posts or images.

I want to see things my friends post themselves, or if they share a direct link themselves.  But I guess I have yet to see a re-share of already posted content on Facebook that is actually useful to me.  I've tried going through the Newsfeed settings but am not finding anything that really does what I want it to do.  Is something like this even possible?  Or should I be looking for some sort of Greasemonkey script or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth you can now (at least on the mobile apps, I think the site, too) mark a post and say "hide all posts from *Blah*" that has gone a long way toward what I was originally asking for.  It doesn't stop all obnoxious posts, but it does keep the driveby riff raff unseen.  Now at least a person has to actually share from an original source rather than simply clicking the "Share" button from within another Facebook feed.

Comment: Thanks, I've now started using "Hide all from" much more aggressively. There seems to be an infinite number of these pages though, so a generic solution would be awesome if it existed.

Comment: @sundar I've been using this loads too... but now I'm wondering if there's a) a way to undo it, or b) a way to see what you've hidden this way?! See -> http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/83065/9183

Answer (score 0):

Social Fixer plugin by Math and then add filters. Furthermore Ad preferences, open all/everything and unclick all you can find.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit?  It's a bit jumbled as-is.