# How do I undo "Hide all from <page/non-friend-person>" in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Facebook frequently shows me things that my friends Like (not share), so I use this "hide all from" functionality quite frequently (eg. there are a million different Minions pages I have hidden because some of my family are Minion-mad):

[image: Hide all from Radio City]

I'm wondering how you "undo" whatever clicking this link does (eg. if I did it accidentally, or changed my mind)? Note: I have never "Liked" this Radio City page, so going and Liking it is not the same as undoing this. I want to stop it being hidden, but I do not want to Like/follow/whatever; I just want it to be allowed back in my stream if somebody shares/Likes something from there.

I have tried visiting the hidden page directly, but I cannot see any options there (or even an indication I have done something).

I've tried News Feed Preferences (which is commonly cited as where you can fix this), but it only gives options for setting people as "See First", unfollowing people, and reconnecting (un-unfollowing). The reconnect page does *not* list the pages I have clicked the above "Hide all" option for (it shows only pages I liked and unfollowed, or friends I unfollowed... I have never Liked/friended the people/pages I used the "Hide all" option on).

I would be very surprised if there is no way to "undo" this, but I just can't find a way. I've seen many people asking the same question online, and there are no correct responses (many point to the News Feed Preferences page, but I've checked many times; these pages do not get listed in there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do that.

Facebook has a long history of finely restricting user options regarding what shows up in their feed- by removing previous features or options unannounced, deliberately changing user-selected preferences without the user's knowledge, and deliberately nerfing user-discovered workarounds to the limitations Facebook has imposed, even introducing features designed to give the user a slight perception of control, bundled tightly with larger changes which in fact reduce user control.

Facebook very frequently will have help and FAQ articles which are totally out of date and incorrect. Most of the time, said help articles suggest that a feature or option exists, when in reality it was deliberately removed (or removed, and re-added, and removed again, and re-added again but in a different way, and removed again).

This just is one of those various little items; it's an option which appears to give some measure of control to the user, but it's an option whose control Facebook keeps control far out of the hands of the user.

Comment: I reported this in FB, and got this response: "Your feedback will be used to improve Facebook. Thanks for taking the time to make a report."